# Does deployment status on a custom object persist through promotion to production?

Tags: custom-object, change-set

If I mark a custom object "In Development", and put it into a change-set, will it still be "In Development" after that change-set has been uploaded to the production org?

In that case, if there are several dependent custom objects being deployed together, does it not make sense to mark them all "Deployed" before they go into the change-set? Because otherwise, while each deployment status on the custom objects was being updated in production, some custom objects would be accessible while others were not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The status of a custom object is exactly the same (e.g. "In Development") once deployed through a change set. Just because you're promoting to production doesn't mean that it's ready to be deployed to all users (e.g. you might yet have some modifications to field security, etc before you release the object). You must manually "deploy" objects in order for them to be accessible to non-administrators.